# Is there a way to read multiple textboxes within a for C#

Tags: c#, textbox

Is there a better way of doing this block of code? I want it inside of a for

```
            points[0] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            points[1] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            points[2] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            points[3] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            points[4] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            points[5] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
            points[6] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
            points[7] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
```

The index [i] does not work within textBox[i].Text

```
for(int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                points[i] = Convert.ToDouble(textBox[i].Text);
            }
```

Comment: You can create an array from those textboxes and then loop over the array. Or if they are the only textboxes in your form contains you can use the this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() expression to loop over them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this adding a *using Linq;*

```
var points = new [] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5,textBox6, textBox7}
                    .Select(x => double.Parse(x.Text)).ToArray();
```

This will create an array from your textboxes then on this sequence we apply the Select extension to enumerate each element and parsing its content to a double. The resulting sequence is finally converted to an array.

Of course this assumes a lot about the conversion in double of your inputs and the correctness of your inputs. If you are not sure about the presence of characters that represent a double value in your inputs then you need a more traditional approach, adding a check in the conversion process.

```
List<double> p = new List<double>();
var tb = new []{ textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4,
                 textBox5, textBox6, textBox7,};

for(int i = 0; i < tb.Length; i++)
   if(double.TryParse(tb[i].Text, out double temp))
       p.Add(temp);

var points = p.ToArray();
```